# /dev/kvm not found in Android Studio (Windows 10)

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I was using Android studio on windows 8.1 and it was working fine. Now I upgraded to windows 10 with a clean install and installed android studio. When I open AVD manager and creates a new emulator, it says **/dev/kvm not found**. I tried these after googling but nothing worked for me-

1. Go to sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and install **intelhaxm-android.exe**
2. Download a fresh copy of Intel HAXM and install, but it says **failed to configure driver: unknown error. failed to open driver**.
3. Re-install HAXM from SDK manager, but it says **Windows blocked the installation of a digitally unsigned driver. Uninstall the program or device that uses the driver and check the publisher's website for a digitally signed version of the driver**
4. Downloading workground patch for HAXM, extract to haxm folder and Run as administrator.

My System

OS- Windows 10

Processor- Intel Core i3 third gen

Intel Virtual Technology already enabled from bios.

Hyper-V is also unchecked

I found that, when I start my PC by disabling driver signature enforcement, the emulator is working fine..

Comment: This is a known bug by Intel, it is something Microsoft changed in their latest Windows 10 Anniversary update. Look here for further information: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221594

Comment: Try this link with parameter 4 like this "HaxInst64.exe /i intelhaxm.inf 4"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527278/dev-kvm-not-found-error-on-windows-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least its solved i justa instled the new HAXM version 6.0.4 at this will work: 
Here is the link:
[HAXM  v6.0.4](http://At%20least%20its%20solved%20i%20justa%20instled%20the%20new%20HAXM%20version%206.0.4%20at%20this%20will%20work:%20%20Here%20is%20the%20link:%20https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=2215940038000&name=haxm-windows_v6_0_4.zip&token=ABZ6GAcJPbnp1m0PTnhNEX5OdbqTUxurqQ%3A1474657868650&id=221594&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAfNJrcdGvHkK-lZH-cY23j8Lcbeow%3A1474657868650)

Comment: Uninstalled haxm from android studio and from control panel and then downloaded it from intel official website. After installing it is working..