# Android Studio /dev/kvm is not found

Tags: android

Android Studio error:

> /dev/kvm is not found

when I want to use VM to test app. I have already Installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and `<sdk>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/InstalledHAXM.exe` 
VM serve is open in BIOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["/dev/kvm not found "error on windows in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527278/dev-kvm-not-found-error-on-windows-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You could install the qemu first, by using de code:
 `sudo apt install qemu`

and then you have to improve your user permissions on it
by:

```
sudo adduser <yourUserHere> /dev/kvm/
```

check if it works:

> ls -al /dev/kvm

and that is all!
I'd hope you solved it.

Comment: duplicate question

Comment: sudo adduser $USER kvm