# Unable to install HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, virtualization, haxm

I am unable to install Intel HAXM on my PC. I enabled the virtualization in system BIOS settings but it still says "Driver error" and "not installed properly". My CPU is Intel i3 running on x86 architecture. And therefore I'm unable to run AVD. It says "dev/kvm not found".

Any answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["/dev/kvm not found "error on windows in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527278/dev-kvm-not-found-error-on-windows-in-android-studio)